template typename field implementation leading to vague CLANG compiler error : cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration specifier
I'm migrating some old C++ code that I didn't author. It hasn't built in years, and honestly not sure what version of C++ it was last compiled against.
One thing I'm doing is compiling the new code against both CLANG/LLVM and MS visual studio compiler. Mostly, this is because I find CLANG a bit more informative. But in this case, its coming with an error I'm a little perplexed on. Furthermore, I can't repro the error when I use MS compiler.
First off, here is the code. This is all in a *.h file.  :
class FieldMap
{
    public:
};

class Information
{
    public:
};

class LogPoint
{
public:
    // Called when this LogPoint has been hit.
    void FlushLogPoint();    
};

template <Information* info, class FooBarClass>
class Log_Template
{
public:    
    static LogPoint getLog;

private:
    static FieldMap s_field; 
};

template <Information* info, class FooBarClass>
typename FieldMap Log_Template<info, FooBarClass>::s_field = (FooBarClass::EnumerateFields); // WARNING HERE 'Expected a qualified name after typename'

template <Information* info, class FooBarClass>
LogPoint typename Log_Template<info, FooBarClass>::getLog(info, &s_field); // ERROR HERE : 

Assuming I use CLANG - I get a few warnings and 2 errors:
The warnings, on this line :
typename FieldMap Log_Template<info, FooBarClass>::s_field = (FooBarClass::EnumerateFields); // WARNING HERE 

Warning     expected a qualified name after 'typename'  ConsoleApp  
Warning     expected a qualified name after 'typename'  ConsoleApp  


The errors, on this line :
LogPoint typename Log_Template<info, FooBarClass>::getLog(info, &s_field); 

Error       cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration specifier  
Error       expected ')'    


With that summarized, I have a few questions :

Any thoughts on why 1 compiler would error here, and not the other?
Why would the 'typename' be switched around in each of the above (it comes before the returned type in s_field, and after the returned type in getLog).


typename usage is wrong. FieldMap and Log_Template are not dependent names.

getLog(info, &s_field) - LogPoint does not have a constructor w/ 2 paraneters.

When is the "typename" keyword necessary?'
